# Особый обход Dictionary

Tags: c#, коллекции

Например есть коллекция:

```
Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
             {"A", 1},
             {"B", 3},
             {"C", 1},
             {"D", 7}
        };
```

Key - имя задачи, Value - сколько раз нужно запустить.

Как эффективно обойти коллекцию что бы результат был:

```
A
B
C
D
B
D
B
D
D
D
D
D
```

То есть обойти коллекцию по кругу, такой себе RoundRobin для Dictionary..

Вот пробую так:

```
int runCount = d.Sum(p => p.Value);
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < runCount; ++j)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d.ElementAt(i).Key);
            --d[d.ElementAt(i).Key];
            if (d.ElementAt(i).Value == 0)
            {
                d.Remove(d.ElementAt(i).Key);
                // сдвинуть указатель назад так как d.Count уменьшилось.
                --i;
            }
            ++i;
            // если пройден n-ый обход переместить указатель на первую запись коллекции.
            if (i == d.Count) i = 0;
        }
```

Но, является ли мое решение эффективным или может есть другие способы обхода таким образом коллекции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А давайте по-простому?

```
static IEnumerable<string> GenerateInterleavedSeq(Dictionary<string, int> d)
{
    while (d.Keys.Count > 0)
    {
        // ToList нужно, чтобы получить копию
        foreach (var key in d.Keys.ToList())
        {
            yield return key;
            if (--d[key] == 0)
                d.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Вы получаете `IEnumerable<string>` и делаете с ним что хотите.

Проверка: http://ideone.com/W2ojIT

---

Учтите, что функция уничтожает переданный ей экземпляр `Dictionary`, так что если он нужен дальше, скопируйте его заблаговременно.

Answer (score 2):

> Но, является ли мое решение эффективным

Однозначно нет. `ElementAt` для словаря перебирает проходит по всем элементам с меньшими индексами в нём каждый раз.

> может есть другие способы обхода таким образом коллекции

```
Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int> { {"A", 1}, {"B", 3}, {"C", 1}, {"D", 7} };

string[] keys = d.Keys.ToArray();
int[] values = d.Values.ToArray();

for (bool run = true; run; )
  {
  run = false;

  for (int q=0; q<d.Count; ++q)
    if (values[q] > 0)
      {
      Console.WriteLine(keys[q]);
      if(--values[q] > 0)
        run  = true;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю насколько эффективно(в целом, не очень), но можно использовать следующий цикл, который, на мой взгляд, гораздо проще воспринимается:

```
while(d.Count != 0)
{
    d = d.Where(p => p.Value > 0).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Key);
        return p.Value - 1;
    });
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Хороший вариант.